# Selecting the power source for load using MOSFETs only?

Tags: power, mosfet, batteries, battery-operated

I'm looking for the circuit to automatically switch the load (< 0.5 A) between the main power source (USB) and back-up (battery) without a specialized IC and without the functionality of charging the battery.

I found two options:

- with 2 diodes
- diode from the main source and switchable P-MOSFET from the battery
  [image]

I wonder if a similar solution can be implemented with MOSFETs only and came up with the following circuit:

[image]

Where `VDC` is the external power source, `+BATT` is voltage from battery, and `VCC` is the output voltage (automatically switched).

To my understanding (I'm not an EE) this should work as follows:

- if `VDC` is connected:

  - the top P-MOSFET connects the `VDC` to `VCC` since the lower N-MOSFET shortens the gate of top P-MOSFET to `GND` and opens it
  - other P-MOSFETs are closed.
  - `VDC` = `VCC`
- if `VDC` is not connected:

  - the `VDC` is pulled to `GND`, it opens the left bottom P-MOSFET, which pulls the top P-MOSFET to the `VCC` and closes it to prevent the back-flow from `VCC` to `VDD`
  - P-MOSFET connected to battery is open and connects the battery to load
  - `VCC` = `+BATT`

My questionas are:

- Is it going to work? In case if `VDC` is USB and `+BATT` is 3xAAA batteries? Or if `+BATT` is a LiIon battery?
- Is this solution any better in terms of saving energy than option with 2 diodes and/ one diode and mosfet? Are the voltage drops lower in such schematic?
- Are there any other problems in this schematics except the hustle to find P-mosfers which can be open from small batteries voltage?
- This circuit is going to work only if `VDC` > (`+BATT` +  body voltage drop on right bottom P-MOSFET)?

Comment: As I understand, in given circuits the P-FETs function as reverse polarity protection, and because of that the drain and source should be reversed (interchanged) intentionally according to [this](https://hackaday.com/2011/12/06/reverse-voltage-protection-with-a-p-fet/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle this circuit should work, however here are two suggestions:

- Remove the \$100k\Omega\$ resistor between `VCC` and the leftmost PFET. This resistor is slowing down the gate charging of the upper PFET during the `VDC` to `BATTERY` switchover. Meaning that, for a couple of miliseconds the battery might discharge into `VDC` if the latter \$VDC< V_{BAT} - V_{BD}\$.
- Add some capacitance at the node `VCC` in order to account for voltage dips during the switchover.

**Update#1**

The following simulation introduces a buffering capacitor \$C_1\$ which speeds up the gate capacitance charging of the upper PFET.
Essentially the capacitor \$C_1\$ is charged when the `VCC` is active, and once the latter is disconnected, the capacitor discharges into the gate capacitance of the upper PFET.

[image: circuit_1]

Comment: I did doubt if that resistor was necessary, and my concern is if without it there could be potentially a situation when VCC is shortened to GND. Is it possible?
Regarding the capacitor: there will be a voltage regulator downstream with the incoming capacitor. I'll count for that.

Comment: If you also want to cover this malfunction, you could keep the resistor but also add some additional voltage buffering for charging the gate capacitance of the upper mosfet. I will update my answer with some small simulation.

Comment: Thank you! Probably, I also need to test this circuit in hardware.